# Magento 2 core_config_data table missing error for no apparent reason?

Tags: magento2

I need some help.  Upon trying to log into my Magento 2 website this evening I had a database error.  I immediately went to SSH and put the site into maintenance mode to reset everything and recompile, and restart, etc.  Now I currently have the error that the core_config_data table is missing. So when I try to put it back into production mode I get the following error on the command window:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'my_database.core_config_data' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `core_config_data` AS `main_table`

Using M2 2.3.3 and PHP 7.1
The site was working normally all day (the first error shows at 7:30 pm) and the front end was showing until I put it into maintenance mode (midnight).  But the admin section could not be accessed.

I tried to recreate the table in SQL but got the following error:

#1813 - Tablespace for table '`my_database`.`core_config_data`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT.

If anyone has any suggestions I would be grateful for them as this is a live retail site and I need to get it back online.

Comment: this can help you. https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2-x/core-config-data-doesn-t-exist/td-p/64780

Answer (score -1):

According to your error message, it seems that you Magento have installed but some database schema query didn't get executed. Please check your database for the 'core_config_data' table. If not there create it manually or reinstall Magento 2.